# Google Account Payments Verify

Tags: google-cloud-platform, payment, verification

In order to complete your request, we need to further confirm the 18-character alphanumeric Billing Account ID on your account.

Comment: Yes. That means that in order for them to complete your requestion, you need to verify the 18-character alphanumberic Billing Account ID on your account. The instructions you received with that message should tell you how to do so. If it's still unclear, contact Google Support via their site; they have access to both your account and what they're asking you to do. SO is not Google Account Support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **customer support** question. See: [Why customer support questions are off-topic here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) .

Answer (score 1):

Log in to the Google Cloud Console. In the left panel go to `Billing`. Select either `Go to linked billing account` or `Manage billing accounts`, or similar. In the right panel note `My Billing Account`. This is the Account ID that Google is requesting.